# Application modularity with Vue.js and local NPM packages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vue-cli-3, modularity

I'm trying to build a modular application in Vue via the `vue-cli-service`. The main app and the modules are separated projects living in different folders, the structure is something like this:

```
-- app/package.json
      /src/**
-- module1/package.json
          /src**
-- module2/package.json
          /src**
```

The idea is to have the Vue app completely agnostic about the application modules that can be there at runtime, the modules themself are compiled with `vue-cli-service build --target lib` in a local `moduleX/dist` folder, pointed with the package.json "main" and "files" nodes.

My first idea (now just for development speed purposes) was to add the modules as local NPM packages to the app, building them with a watcher and serving the app with a watcher itself, so that any change to the depending modules would (I think) be distributed automatically to the main app.

So the `package.json` of the app contains dependencies like:

```
...
"module1": "file:../module1",
"module2": "file:../module2",
...
```

This dependencies are mean to be removed at any time, or in general be composed as we need, the app sould just be recompiled and everything should work.

I'm trying to understand now how to dynamically load and activate the modules in the application, as I cannot use the dynamic import like this:

```
import(/* webpackMode: "eager" */ `module1`).then(src => {
    src.default.boot();
    resolve();
});
```

Because basically I don't know the 'module1', 'module2', etc...

In an OOP world I would just use dependency injection retrieving classes implementing a specific interface, but in JS/TS I'm not sure it is viable.

There's a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the reason for limiting the set of modules at build time instead of at runtime ? I mean you can easily let webpack to build each and every module to its own chunk and then at runtime decide which one to load (base on some json config)...

Comment: @MichalLevý That's exactly what I don't know how to do. Trying with the dynamic import, as you can see on the question, I still have the problem to HARDCODE the string that says "module1", "module2", etc... I want something like: "import all the modules that expose this interface". Or the equivalent in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juggling with `package.json` doesn't  sound like a good idea to me - doesn't scale. What I would do:

1. Keep all available "modules" in `package.json`
2. Create separate `js` file (or own prop inside `package.json`) with all available configurations (for different clients for example)

```js
module.exports = {
   'default': ['module1', 'module2', 'module3'],
   'clientA': ['module1', 'module2', 'module4'],
   'clientB': ['module2', 'module3', 'module4']
}
```

3. tap into VueCLI build process - best example I found is [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4093) and create js file which will run before each build (or "serve") and using simple template (for example [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#template)) generate new js file which will boot configured modules based on the value of some ENV variable. See following (pseudo)code (remember this runs inside node during build):

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const _ = require('lodash')
const modulesConfig = require(`your module config js`)

const configurationName = process.env.MY_APP_CONFIGURATION ?? 'default'
const modules = modulesConfig[configurationName]

const template = fs.loadFileSync('name of template file')
const templateCompiled = _.template(template)
const generatedJS = templateCompiled({ `modules`: modules })
fs.writeFileSync('bootModules.js', generatedJS)
```

4. Write your template for `bootModules.js`. Simplest would be:

```
<% _.forEach(modules , function(module) { %>import '<%= module %>' as <%= module %><% }); %>;
```

5. import `bootModules.js` into your app
6. Use `MY_APP_CONFIGURATION` ENV variable to switch desired module configuration - works not just during development but you can also setup different CI processes targeting same repo with just different `MY_APP_CONFIGURATION` values

This way you have all configurations at one place, you don't need to change `package.json` before every build, you have simple mechanism to switch between different module configurations and every build (bundle) contains only the modules needed....

Answer (score 0):

> In an OOP world I would just use dependency injection retrieving classes implementing a specific interface, but in JS/TS I'm not sure it is viable.

Why not?

More than this, with JS/TS you are not restricted to use classes implementing a specific interface: you just need to define the interface (i.e. the `module.exports`) of your modules and respecting it in the libraries entries (vue build lib).

**EDIT:** reading comments probably I understood the request.

Each module should respect following interface (in the file which is the entry of the vue library)

```
export function isMyAppModule() {
  return true;
}

export function myAppInit() {
  return { /* what you need to export */ };
}
```

Than in your app:

```
require("./package.json").dependencies.forEach(name => {
  const module = require(name);

  if(! module.isMyAppModule || module.isMyAppModule() !== true) return;

  const { /* the refs you need */ } = module.myAppInit();

  // use your refs as you need
});
```

Comment: Still I'll need to hardcode the string to identify the module. My problem is that I would like to find a way to make this part automated based on what's referenced by the package.json of the app.

Comment: No wait @tanathos , if the list of the modules is in `package.json` it means you know it at build time. I was thinking your app, starting, reads the (example) `modules` directory to load the run-time modules and then it's easy for each module to calculate the name of the file to `require`. While if the list of the modules is in `package.json` file, which method to install them are you thinking about (obviously different from the standard build process, otherwise you wouldn't have asked this question)? Can you please clarify your scenario?

Comment: Reading various comments @tanathos probably I understood the request; could you please check my updated answer?

Comment: Sure. The app will need to be installed for different clients, each of them needing different modules. So my idea was to just change the package.json (now the modules are local npm packages, but in the future they'll be distributed to an internal npm repo) leaving the code of the app just the same. The modules will always expose a single boot() method that I'll call after the loading of the module itself is done.

Comment: I'll give it a try ASAP @Daniele Ricci

Comment: We crossed our comment @tanathos ... to trust a package is a module of your app only on the method `boot` it a bit risky... it's quite easy a package which is not a module of your app exports a `boot` function... It's better to trust a function name which is for sure only in your interface (something like `isMyAppModule`) then calling `boot` or `myAppInit` makes no difference.

Comment: Does it what you need, @tanathos ?

Comment: Still didn't had the time to test the proposed solutions, as I'll be back on the project I'll answer here